# How to test server-side code in localhost ?

Tags: php, node.js, localhost, server-side

I know this question may sound crazy. But my question is is there a possible way to test the server side scripts on localhost ? Things like PHP Mail function does not work on localhost. What is the procedure followed by big Companies when they're developing it on localhost ?

Comment: I think big companies doesn't test php's `mail` function on their test envorinments.

Comment: @HddnTHA I know that. Can't u realize that php's mail function is just an example ?

Comment: I just like to know the procedure

Comment: It helps if you work with abstractions. Instead of calling "mail" directly you could create a mail interface. Then you create an implementation of that interface for production use which actually calls `mail` and another implementation for testing which, for example, writes the mail to a file. The same works for other services (database, filesystem - you name it). If you're using PHPUnit for unit tests you can create those test-implementations on the fly using [test doubles](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html).

Comment: You you may be able to see what happened on server by reading log data of server. You can do anything on client, so if you can see what happend on server, you can examine how the server works. This is a part of testing.